# What should I do if a recruiter contacted me for starting an application but has not replied in two days?

Tags: job-search, recruitment

The other day I received an email from a recruiter from a big company, about a particular role and asked me to give the name, graduation date, VISA status and other details to start the application.

The email came in at evening time, approximately 5pm. I could not see it at that time, I woke up and replied to the email at 4am.

After that there has been no contact from the recruiter and I am worried. What should I do and will the recruiter contact me or not?

Comment: What are you worried about? Do you want a job at the company that the recruiter says they work for?

Comment: @ZoeHowlett yes, I first time got such email from a recruiter of a company of my choice. I don't know whether the recruiter would contact me again or not.

Comment: It is completely reasonable to follow up your initial email with another email checking on the status.

Answer (score 3):

It is completely reasonable to send a follow up e-mail a couple of days (maybe a week) after your first contact with a recruiter. If nothing else, you are able to keep a connection with this recruiter and the next time there is a position available they may think of you.

I would suggest an e-mail/message something simple, suggesting that you are interested in the position and would like more information. The message should be short and to the point.

It is also reasonable to assume that the process to hire a new recruit can take more then a few days. I wouldn't worry too much and after about a week I would send a follow up e-mail.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities here, both related:

- The recruiter has picked a number of people to contact, and as you are later responding it may take them a few more days to get through people back to you.
- The recruiter has picked a number of people and based on these responses has who they think they need, so have "ghosted" you.  In this scenario you may never hear from them again.  Ghosting has been quite common from recruiters for several years now, even at advanced stages of hiring, and is apparently now also becoming a thing from workers in the current job market, leaving jobs without resigning, just not coming back.

What to do?  Follow up with the recruiter, but keep searching for other opportunities.  If something leads somewhere great, but get used to ghosting it will happen at all levels as you go for jobs so don't get hung up about it.